# Binding ASP.Net MVC model with dates in custom format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding, date-formatting, bootstrap-datepicker

What's the best way of binding a MVC model which contains *DateTime* fields in some custom format?

This is the view, which uses *bootstrap datepicker*:

```
@model ViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DateFormat)
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4>
            <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="@Model.DateFormat">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateFrom, Model.DateFormat, new { @class = "form-control text-right" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4>
            <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-format="@Model.DateFormat">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateTo, Model.DateFormat, new { @class = "form-control text-right" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

There are no script sections involved. The date pickers are displayed correctly and dates can be selected.

When the form is POSTed, the selected date values are null. They weren't bound and the view returns with the inputs validated in a red border.

This is the Back-end code using *.Net Framework*, not *Core*:

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public string DateFormat { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateTo { get; set; }
    // some other properties...
}

using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
public class RecordsController : Controller
{
    public string CustomDateFormat { get; set; }

    protected override IAsyncResult BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        string customDateFormat = DetermineDateFormatBasedOnUserPreferences();
        // examples: "dd/MM/yyyy" or "MM/dd/yyyy" or "d/M/yy" or whatever...
        CustomDateFormat = customDateFormat;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new ViewModel()
        {
            DateFormat = CustomDateFormat,
            DateFrom = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1),
            DateTo = DateTime.Today
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        // Problem is here. viewModel.DateFrom and viewModel.DateTo are null.
        DoWork(viewModel.DateFrom, viewModel.DateTo);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Tried setting CustomDateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy" in the controller.

Comment: I understand you want to define the format of your DateTime value ? Try to assign the format on the attribute: [DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime DateFrom{ get; set; } And on your view try it @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.DateForm)

Comment: @JordiJordi your suggestion is not valid because the format is known at runtime. Some function gets it, like DetermineDateFormatBasedOnUserPreferences()

Comment: Maybe you can use your own DateTime ValidationAttribute extension class and if is null return true ?

Comment: The format in the textbox that is submitted must match the culture on the server. If it does not, then you must use a custom ModelBinder for the date property (or in the view, use javascript to convert to ISO (`yyyy-MM-dd`) format which will always be correctly bound

Comment: @StephenMuecke Does the ISO format you mentioned bind always correctly, regardless of the server's Thread.Culture?

Comment: @SamuGG, Yes it will